# C# Authentication - setting UserRole as global variable? 

Tags: c#, authentication, authorization

Our dba has an SPROC for authentication that returns the User Role only if successful validation occurs.

In my custom authentication class, the ValidateUser method hits this SPROC via an Entity Model & Domain Service, and since the SPROC returns the RoleName on successful validation, I already have an instance of it.

When it comes time to run the GetRolesForUser method in my custom RoleProvider, I suppose I could write another SPROC to grab the RoleName again, but that seems a bit redundant, since I've already retrieved the role. I'd love to be able to cache the User Role in my ValidateUser method, access it in my GetRolesForUser method, and ride off into the sunset. Not only would this save time writing an SPROC, but it would also limit the number of db calls the app is making.

Thoughts?

Scott

Comment: Do you have performance concerns you're trying to address/optimize?  I'd be leery about mixing authorization with authentication in the name of performance unless you see a real need.  There's nothing "wrong" with the approach, but it is unexpected behavior.

Comment: No, not particularly. I'm just trying to implement custom authentication and a custom role provider, as my client already has an existing DB for authentication & authorization for all of their projects. Since their SOP is to return the role on successful authentication (the dbo.Logon SPROC is standard in every db they build - input username, pw, appID & it returns roleName if successful), it just doesn't make sense to make a second db call for a role when I already have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats correct. When you are running your custom RoleProvider, you already have the session state which you can use to store the value of "RoleName".. Alternately, you can extend the MembershipUser call to include a string field for "RoleName" which you can populate in the first call and then assign back to the context.user.

I would not suggest Cache object here becuase the Roles would be tied to a user.

Comment: I've extended my user class (public partial class User : UserBase) to include a public string UserRole { get; set; }. I'm not sure how to save & later access data on that particular class. Am I wrong in extending User : UserBase? Should it be MembershipUser? (I'm a recent convert from LAMP to .NET, so forgive my ignorance). I can't use sessions to store the data, as this will eventually be a silverlight Out of Browser app, so session won't be available.

Comment: It should be the MembershipUser so that you can access it within the context.

Comment: Any idea how I do that? I've googled it and spent a couple hours this morning trying to get it wired up. Seems like I need a custom MembershipProvider too, and that's where I'm getting really stuck.A simple code example/walkthrough would be a winner, here. I don't want to store this data in a db, and every example does so.